# AWS: Windows EC2 Serial Console fails to start

Tags: amazon-ec2

When I try to invoke the EC2 Serial Console for my Windows 2019 Servers I get an empty black screen.

I have opened up port 22 Inbound from 0.0.0.0/0
and
my user role has the policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSerialConsoleAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2-instance-connect:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what my browser looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enter a ?, and then press Enter and the SAC commands will get loaded.